# I can't generate html body (template form) in vs code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I searched about it and there is no solution for that. The main construction is pressing the Tab button while holding the exclamation mark. [constructions for generating HTML body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsOAW.png)
I tried to fix it with settings, different combinations, restaring. They didn't work

Comment: You haven't yet explained what the problem is.

Comment: As far as I know, VS Codes does not specifically recognize or handle `!` keypresses so I have no idea what it has to do with HTML templating. What are you wanting to do, exactly? Are you trying to copy that HTML from the codegrepper.com page into VSCode?

Comment: Make sure you have selected `HTML` as your language mode at the bottom right. Usually it is `plain text` for the newly created unsaved file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want the basic HTML body in VS code. Write "html:5" and then press "tab".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is I was doing right. In the right bottom corner there is a language detector which was set to auto detecting. I needed to change that and Voila!

Answer (score 0):

Try typing exclamation mark (!) and see if a popup like this appears:
[image]

If It does then press `tab` key or `enter` key.
If it doesn't then type `Html:5` and then press `Tab` key.
Check if The file you have saved have a `.html` extension or check the language mode.

Comment: This happens if Your cpu has high usage and vs code prevents lag by turning of the autocomplete.